# How do I get to this point of interest in the Plains of Ashford?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I just ran in a complete circle around this raised area of terrain. At the top, there seems to be a place of interest, but I can't get up there. How do I activate this place of interest?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's in the Tomb of Barradin. I did the same thing during one of the beta weekends.
[image]

Comment: Oh, is that possibly what the little down arrow icon next to the Point of Interest is? I've seen similar up-arrow-icons, for example down where "Victor's Presidium" is on the Vista (I think it's called a Vista).

Comment: @InvaderSkoodge You got it!

Comment: You didn't warn me about the series of near-invincible bosses down there :P